# Casting pointer form derived class method to base class

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

Let's say I want to create a hierarchy that reacts to certain event encoded in string. For example commands coming from network. Idea is that there is a `Base` class that handling network connection, receiving buffer, splitting it etc and handling of commands reaction is in derived class (derived class can also add some new words to be handled). So my solution is:

```
class Base {
public:
    typedef void (Base::*Method)();
    typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, Method> Methods;

    void reactToA();
    void reactToB();

    Base() :
       methods{ 
          { "A", &Base::reactToA },
          { "B", &Base::reactToB }
       }
    {
    }
    void action( const std::string &s )
    {
        auto f = methods.find( s );
        if( f != methods.end() )
           (*this.*)(f->second)();
    }

protected:
    Methods methods;
};

class Child : public Base {
public:
    void reactToB();
    void reactToC();

    Child() {
        methods[ "B" ] = static_cast<Method>( &Child::reactToB );
        methods[ "C" ] = static_cast<Method>( &Child::reactToC );
    }
};
```

So I have to cast pointer to `Child` method to pointer to `Base` method. Is that cast well defined? Is there more elegant (or correct, if this leads to UB) solution?

Comment: You don't need to do the cast you will always use the instance to perform callbacks.

Comment: as it is written `Base` is not a base class of `Child` this looks like the kind of problem that proper inheritance would handle even without the cast.

Comment: Yep, you're reinventing polymorphism. Any reason ?

Comment: @Quentin because polymorphism as provided by c++ cannot handle this.

Comment: @AnisBelaid it is not, added method `action()`, sorry I thought it is obvious how it can be used.

Comment: @Slava Yes it can. Just drop the pointers and make `reactToX()` virtual.

Comment: @Quentin added method `reactToC()` point is derived class may add additional events and that would not require modification of base class (which could be in a library). With polymorphism I would have to modify Base

Comment: @Slava - Even with the solution that you are pursuing, it would still be impossible to call those additional events from the base class.

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps I am showing concept what I want to achieve, my code can be incorrect, but I hope shows my intention. That the purpose of asking, is it not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [expr.static.cast]:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to member of `D` of type *cv1* `T`” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to
>   member of `B`” of type *cv2* `T`, where `B` is a base class (Clause 10) of `D`, if a valid standard conversion from
>   “pointer to member of `B` of type `T`” to “pointer to member of `D` of type `T`” exists (4.11), and *cv2* is the same
>   *cv*-qualification as, or greater *cv*-qualification than, *cv1*. [...] If class `B` contains the original member, or is a
>   base or derived class of the class containing the original member, the resulting pointer to member points to
>   the original member. **Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**

In our case, `&Base::reactToB` can be converted to `&Child::reactToB`, but since `Base` does *not* contain the original member, the behavior is undefined.

You'd have to store something like a `std::function<void(Base*)>` or `void(*)(Base*)`.

If the former, you could add a member function to `Base` like:

```
template <typename C>
void addMethod(std::string const& name, void (C::*method)()) {
    methods[name] = [method](Base* b){
        (static_cast<C*>(b)->*method)();
    };
}

addMethod("B", &Child::reactToB);
```

If the latter, you could do something like:

```
methods[ "B" ] = +[](Base* b){ 
   static_cast<Child*>(b)->reactToB();
};
```

Comment: @KubaOber sometimes (especially on handling network) even small overhead of `std::function` could be noticeable. Also I may want to limit callable to be methods of derived class rather than anything callable.

Comment: Guys. The `addMethod()` solution *does use* `std::function`. Only the function pointer version with the `+` does not.

Comment: Hmm, is `addMethod` simply implementing `std::bind`, then? I'm still a bit surprised at the whole wheel reinvention. The second method, using a true local free function through the pointer-to-function conversion via `+` is the real deal, as it still stores a simple function pointer in the container, and has the overhead of an indirection through one cacheline worth of machine code in the lambda body. That's the real winner over `std::function` and if you're performance-crazy, you can see the results of that (about a dozen cacheline misses less or so until the method starts running).

Answer (score 2):

With just a tiny bit of overhead of the generic function pointer `std::function`, you can have fully defined behavior and much more flexibility since you can call pretty much anything, not only methods:

```
class Base { 
public:
  typedef std::function<void()> Callable;
  typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, Callable> Callables;
  void action(const std::string &s) {
    auto f = callables.find(s);
    if (f != callables.end()) f->second();
  }
protected:
  Callables callables;
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
  void reactToA() {}
  void reactToB() {}
public:
  Derived1() {
    callables["A"] = std::bind(&Derived1::reactToA, *this);
    callables["B"] = std::bind(&Derived1::reactToB, *this);
  }
};

static void reactToE();    

class Derived2 : public Derived {
  void reactToB() {}
  void reactToC() {}
public:
  Derived2() {
    callables["B"] = std::bind(&Derived2::reactToB, *this);
    callables["C"] = std::bind(&Derived2::reactToC, *this);
    callables["D"] = []{ std::cout << "Hey, what, D now?!" << std::endl; }
    callables["E"] = &reactToE;
  }
};
```